# Including Authentication in the Header of a POST Request using ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to make a request to receive a session Id to integrate with a payment gateway.

```
var m = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("merchant." + merchant_Id + ":" + merchant_pass);
var b64Val = Convert.ToBase64String(m);
var SerSession = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sessionRequest);
var client = new HttpClient();
string _ContentType = "application/json";
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(_ContentType));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", String.Format("Basic {0}", b64Val));

var _UserAgent = "d-fens HttpClient";
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", _UserAgent);
HttpContent _Body = new StringContent(SerSession);
]_Body.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(_ContentType);
HttpResponseMessage response;
response = await  client.PostAsync(api_URL, _Body);
var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
return Ok(content);
```

I am getting (Invalid credentials) and I am sure the credentials I am using are correct. I have tested them in Python and PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
var authenticationString = $"{merchant_Id}:{merchant_pass}";
var base64EncodedAuthenticationString = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(authenticationString));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", base64EncodedAuthenticationString);
```

Comment: It finally worked. Thank you so much :)